# Cordova/Android not finding JDK on OSX and PATH/JAVA_HOME correct

Tags: java, android, macos, cordova

So cordova requirements is still failing for Android after trying and verifying all paths, versions and suggestions.  It's on OSX 10.10.5 and a clean install of Android SDKs/Studio and cordova.  Have tried Apple recommended (export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`) and direct paths with same failed result.  Have verified both java/javac are in the bin directory of the JDK path.

```
sh-3.2# cordova requirements
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: not installed 
Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home

Android SDK: installed 
Android target: installed android-9,android-10,android-19,android-22,android-23,android-24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:22,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
Gradle: installed 
Error: Some of requirements check failed

sh-3.2# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/dzhon/bin:/opt/dzhon/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/rob/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/rob/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/rob/Documents/software/apache-ant-1.9.7/bin

sh-3.2# echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home

sh-3.2# java -version
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)

sh-3.2# javac -version
javac 1.8.0_102

sh-3.2# node -v
v5.3.0

sh-3.2# cordova -v
6.2.0
```

and in ~/.bash_profile:

```
    export ANT_HOME=/Users/rob/Documents/software/apache-ant-1.9.7
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
    export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/rob/Library/Android/sdk
    export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

have also checked all the symlinks:

```
sh-3.2# ls -la /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 20 Jul 11:54 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel  408  6 Jan  2016 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 26 Mar  2015 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 26 Mar  2015 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 26 Mar  2015 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 26 Mar  2015 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 26 Mar  2015 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 26 Mar  2015 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272  6 Jan  2016 A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 26 Mar  2015 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 20 Jul 11:54 CurrentJDK -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents
```

The only thing in digging through the source for cordova-android on gitHub is in check_reqs.js, the error message is:

```
Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
```

rather than as it currently reports:

```
Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
```

Any help greatly appreciated.
Rob

Comment: so I tried downgrading to JDK 1.7 with no improvement.  Downgrading to JDK 1.6 does allow it to pass.  Hope this helps someone.  Still would like to resolve it using the latest JDK though.

Comment: and now there's other cordova build errors that others say are fixed by using JDK 1.8, so back to the original problem

Answer (score 0):

So a number of issues.  check_reqs.js is where the platform/environment checks are done (app/platforms/android/cordova/lib/).  The call to forgivingWhichSync('javac') on line 98 was returning the non-JDK link (as it was using Current, not CurrentJDK):
    /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/javac

By repointing the Current symlink in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/ to CurrentJDK it fixed this first issue:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 21 Jul 12:03 Current -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   59 21 Jul 12:06 CurrentJDK -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents
```

The next issue was a problem with the tryCommand method testing javac.  As correctly noted, javac -version returns the information in stderr.  The issue (at least on OSX) is that the call to child_process.exec on line 44 also returns information in err:

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c javac -version
javac 1.8.0_102
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are     used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files
  -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
  -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```

The handling of the callback to this child_process.exec always triggered an error if err was non null:
    if (err) d.reject(new CordovaError(errMsg));
changing this to only trigger this error if the catchStderr flag was not set now correctly handles the test for javac:
    if (err && !catchStderr) d.reject(new CordovaError(errMsg));

and now success:

```
sh-3.2# cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed .
Android SDK: installed 
Android target: installed android-9,android-10,android-16,android-18,android-19,android-22,android-23,android-24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:16,Google Inc.:Google APIs:18,Google Inc.:Google APIs:22,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
Gradle: installed
```

Unfortunately need to edit check_reqs.js for each project when you cordova platform add android but at least it's now finding everything.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked perfectly when I did the installation with Cordova version 7 and JDK 1.8u131 on OSX. Nothing had to be changed or configured. Possibly the older versions of Cordova had issues.